# Sequelize: updateOnDuplicate not working with unique index in Bulk

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this index:

```
 indexes: [
      {
        name: 'prodotto',
        unique: true,
        fields: ['prodotto'],
      },
    ],
```

But when i do:

```
await db.Product.bulkCreate(
        products,
        {
          updateOnDuplicate: [
            'prodotto',
            'codiceEan',
            'descrizione',
            'aggiuntiva',
            'listino',
            'prezzoMin',
            'giacenza',
            'updatedAt',
          ],
        }
      )
```

Note : products is array of objects containing field called prodotto(index unqie);
But this is not working, any idea why? data is not beign updated

query generated :

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`_id`,`prodotto`,`codiceEan`,`descrizione`,`aggiuntiva`,`listino`,`prezzoMin`,`giacenza`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (NULL,'AR1914/SOLARE',8053841580004,'VASO TONDO 86 SL - SOLARE','','0','218.4',5,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'AR1925/SOLARE',8053841580011,'VASO TONDO 102 SL - SOLARE','','0','252',-14,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'AR1926/SOLARE',8053841580028,'VASO QUADRO 102 SL - SOLARE','','0','252',-36,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'AR1927/SOLARE',8053841580035,'VASO QUADRO 86 SL - SOLARE','','0','218.4',3,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/2009',8055684964232,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Arancio','','735','823.2',1,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/2009-I',8056039169807,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Arancio','Banda Inox','860','963.2',0,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/3027',8055684964256,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Rosso','','635','711.2',0,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/3027-I',8056039169814,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Rosso','Banda Inox','760','851.2',0,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/4003',8055684964249,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Fuxia','','635','711.2',1,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/4003-I',8056039169838,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Fuxia','Banda Inox','760','851.2',0,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/4005',8055684964263,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Violetto','','575','823.2',2,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/4005-I',8056039169791,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Violetto','Banda Inox','675','963.2',1,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/5012',8055684964270,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Blu','','635','711.2',0,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00'),(NULL,'CV-A100/5012-I',8056039169852,'Doccia Solare - Spring - Blu','Banda Inox','760','851.2',1,'2022-05-19 18:59:00','2022-05-19 18:59:00') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `prodotto`=VALUES(`prodotto`),`codiceEan`=VALUES(`codiceEan`),`descrizione`=VALUES(`descrizione`),`aggiuntiva`=VALUES(`aggiuntiva`),`listino`=VALUES(`listino`),`prezzoMin`=VALUES(`prezzoMin`),`giacenza`=VALUES(`giacenza`),`updatedAt`=VALUES(`updatedAt`);
```

Comment: show a generated SQL

Comment: @Anatoly how can i do it?

Comment: turn on `logging` option either in Sequelize options or in the query itself

Comment: @Anatoly looking at that query, it doesn't contain all the data, strange

Comment: And what data are missing?

Comment: @Anatoly my bad, i was reading csv with inputStream and i forgot that i can't use async